Colimits and Cofibrations
I was reading the following lecture notes on algebraic $K$-Theory: https://www.mn.uio.no/math/personer/vit/rognes/kurs/mat9570v10/akt.pdf
I have a question regarding Lemma 5.5.7 on page 124 (in the section of the glueing lemma) that proves a statement about sequential colimits of homotopy equivalences that are compatible with cofibrations in a commutative diagram, namely we get a homotopy equivalence when taking the colimit.

They only shortly sketch the proof where we find compatible homotopies and homotopy inverses using the fact that we have cofibrations and apply HEP, but I would like to see the specific construction of it since they omitted all of it. They also hint at Hatcher, but I’m not satisfied by what is done in Hatcher. I’ve also seen a proof in Tom Dieck’s book, which also required some more technical details, so I was wondering whether there was a direct proof, simply by using the HEP to get compatibility and a well-defined map on the colimit.

That's a standard method turning a homotopy into an equality and is worth to learn properly. Here is the construction.
The maps are constructed in the following inductive procedure: We fix $g_0$ as any homotopy inverse of $f_0$. Suppose now that homotopy inverses up until $f_{n-1}$ are constructed, called $g_i$. We wish to construct $g_n$ as the homotopy inverse of $f_n$ such that $i_n \circ g_{n-1} = g_n \circ j_n$.
Let $g_n'$ be any homotopy inverse of $f_n$. By definition $j_n \circ f_{n-1} = f_n \circ i_n$, so after composing with their homotopy inverses, we deduce $g_n' \circ j_n \simeq i_n \circ g_{n-1}$ realized by a homotopy $H$. As $j_n$ is a cofibration, this extends to a homotopy $\overline{H} : Y_n \times I \to X_n$ starting in $g_n'$ ending in $g_n = \overline{H}(-, 1)$ which by definition restricts to $i_n \circ g_{n-1}$ on $Y_{n-1}$, i.e. $g_n \circ j_n = i_n \circ g_{n-1}$.
